# knockoutJs two way binding not working in foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to perform two way binding in class attribute within Foreach of observable Array.
In the first load, it binds successfully. But when I click on each LI, I want to change class attribute accordingly.

Can you please help me what is wrong here?

Regards
Savas

CarTypeModel

```
appKeyTours.CarType = function (type, count, active) {
    'use strict';
    this.Type = type;
    this.Count = count;
    this.Active = ko.observable(active);
};
```

CarType OBservableArray

```
carTypes: ko.observableArray([
    new appKeyTours.CarType('Full Size', 10, false),
    new appKeyTours.CarType('Compact', 20, true),
]),
```

Car Type click event

```
clickCarType: function (e) {
    e.Active = !e.Active;
},
```

this is HTML

```
                                    <ul data-bind="foreach: carTypes" class="check-square filters-option">
                                        <li data-bind="click: $parent.clickCarType, css:{'active':Active()}" >
                                            <a href="#"><!-- ko text: Type --><!-- /ko --><small>(<!-- ko text: Count --><!-- /ko -->)</small></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
clickCarType: function (e) {
    e.Active(!e.Active());
}
```

instead of

```
clickCarType: function (e) {
    e.Active = !e.Active;
}
```